# ¿Cómo puedo extraer la primera y ultima posición de una palabra dentro de una cadena con javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, scraping, data

Mi problema es simple tengo esto:

Con indexOf obtengo la posicion de https pero necesito extraer ahora la url, como se puede ver hay texto delante y detrás pero no sé de que manera centralizar la extracción sólo de la url

```
const parrafo = 'Silvio Rodriguez Unanse al respaldo• https://www.facebook.com/ 1293';

const palabra = 'https';

console.log(parrafo.indexOf(palabra))
```

Comment: Puedes usar `split()` y luego filtrats el resultado, obteniendo soló los elementos que contengan `https`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Pero con `split()` necesitaría la ultima posición de la palabra, allí es donde me estanco porque dándose el caso de que hayan más palabras delante debo omitirlas pero como las omito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya tienes una [excelente respuesta dada por @Marc](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/477490/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-extraer-la-primera-y-ultima-posici%c3%b3n-de-una-palabra-dentro-de-una-ca/477492#477492). Mi respuesta usa un enfoque diferente, tal como digo en [mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/477490/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-extraer-la-primera-y-ultima-posici%c3%b3n-de-una-palabra-dentro-de-una-ca#comment849935_477490)

Se trata de usar el método [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) sobre la cadena que contiene tus palabras, y separar las palabras mediante el carácter de espacio: `" "`, de esa forma obtendremos un `Array` que contiene todas y cada una de las palabras de la cadena original separadas como elementos del `Array`:

```js
let cadena = 'Silvio Rodriguez Unanse al respaldo• https://www.facebook.com/ 1293';

let palabras = cadena.split(' ');

console.log(palabras);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Una vez obtenido este `Array` es sencillo filtrar las palabras para dejar sólo aquellas que comiencen con `https` (o `http` si fuera el caso). Para ello podemos usar el método [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) aplicado sobre el `Array` y como filtro podemos usar el método [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) sobre cada palabra del `Array` de palabras.

Esto nos da la siguiente primera solución:

```js
let cadena = 'Silvio Rodriguez Unanse al respaldo• https://www.facebook.com/ 1293';
let palabra = 'https';

let palabras = cadena.split(' ');

let urls = palabras.filter(elemento => elemento.includes(palabra));

console.log(urls);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Si estamos seguros que sólo existe una URL en la cadena, podemos extraer la misma del `Array de la siguiente forma:

```
let [ url ] = palabras.filter(elemento => elemento.includes(palabra));
```

```js
let cadena = 'Silvio Rodriguez Unanse al respaldo• https://www.facebook.com/ 1293';
let palabra = 'https';

let palabras = cadena.split(' ');

let [ url ] = palabras.filter(elemento => elemento.includes(palabra));

console.log(url);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Pequeña Mejora**

Podemos mejorar nuestra lógica para los casos en que la cadena tenga más palabras `https` que no sean necesariamente una `url`. Para esto podríamos escribir una función que valide si el elemento analizado es efectivamente una `url`.

Podemos usar la API [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL), aunque no funciona en Internet Explorer ni en Safari, cosa ha tener en cuenta. Por ejemplo:

```js
function isValidURL(str) {
  let isValid;
  try {
    let url = new URL(str);
    isValid = true;
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    isValid = false;
  }
  return isValid;
}
```

Con esta función podemos determinar si una palabra es efectivamente una `url` válida, y la podemos usar en nuestra lógica de la siguiente forma:

```js
function isValidURL(str) {
  let isValid;
  try {
    let url = new URL(str);
    isValid = true;
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(`${e.message}: '${str}'`);
    isValid = false;
  }
  return isValid;
}

let cadena = 'Silvio Rodriguez Unanse al respaldo• https://www.facebook.com/ 1293 ahora en https';
let palabra = 'https';
let palabras = cadena.split(' ');
let [ url ] = palabras.filter(elemento => elemento.includes(palabra) && isValidURL(elemento));

console.log(url);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Con esta pequeña mejora, tenemos la certeza que estamos devolviendo realmente una URL y no simplemente una cadena que contenga la palabra `https`.

Una forma de hacerlo funcionar para el caso de IE y Safari, sería usar una expresión regular. En [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717093/check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url) respuesta del sitio en inglés tienes varios ejemplos de cómo lograr validar una URL con expresiones regulares.

Comment: Excelente y bastante útil, sin negar a dudas es bastante certero el código muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes buscar el indexof de `https` como haces, y después buscar el `indexof` del siguiente espacio a partir del índice de `https`, usando un `substring`, así obtendrías la URL entera:

```
const parrafo = 'Silvio Rodriguez Unanse al respaldo• https://www.facebook.com/ 1293';

const palabra = 'https';

console.log(parrafo.substring(parrafo.indexOf(palabra), parrafo.indexOf(' ', parrafo.indexOf(palabra))));
```

Resultado: `"https://www.facebook.com/"`

Explicación:

Usamos la función `substring` que acepta 2 índices donde cortar el string, en el primero le pasamos el índice de `https` y en el segundo le pasamos el índice del siguiente espacio después de `https`, que para ello usamos `indexOf` de nuevo, pero pasándole 2 parámetros, el primero lo que queremos buscar, y el segundo, el índice a partir del cual buscaremos.

Aquí tienes el [enlace a las pruebas que he hecho](https://jsfiddle.net/9yoxb2e1/).

Comment: Increíble, entendido perfectamente... Muchas gracias!!!! Llevo toda la noche partiéndome la cabeza con esto jaja

Answer (score 1):

Esta opción sacada del ejemplo Marc me dio también es viable y le puse un par de mejoras ya que verifica si hay texto delante y en caso contrario de igual manera obtiene la url y omite espacios, dándose el caso de que existan al final y principio del parrafo con `trim()`, útil si es que la url esta al inicio o al final.

```js
const palabra = 'https';
const parrafo1 = 'Texto https://www.facebook.com';
const parrafo2 = 'Texto https://www.facebook.com Texto';


const filtrado1 = parrafo1.includes('https')
      ?
      parrafo1.substring(parrafo1.indexOf(palabra)).trim().split(' ')[0]
      : 
      'Sin Links';

const filtrado2 = parrafo2.includes('https')
      ? 
      parrafo2.substring(parrafo2.indexOf(palabra)).trim().split(' ')[0]
      :
      'Sin Links';

console.log(`Con texto delante ${filtrado1}`);
console.log(`Sin texto delante ${filtrado2}`);
```